# MSFT Access Query - Why is "Enter Parameter Value" message box popping up?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables:
`tblImport` with fields:

```
locationID locationPartTypeID partName
```

and `tblLocationPart` with fields:

```
locationPartID (key) locationID locationPartTypeID partName
```

I need my MSFT Access query to return a table with all the locationID-locationPartTypeID pairs in tblImport and not in tblLocationPart

Here is my query:

```
SELECT i.locationID, i.locationPartTypeID, i.partName
From tblImport i 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblLocationPart lp
ON lp.locationID = i.locationID
```

I don't understand why Access is giving me "Enter Parameter Value" popup boxes for lp.locationPartTypeID and lp.locationID.

When I leave these popup boxes blank and click OK, the query returns the result I am expecting.

Comment: Check all your field names.

Comment: I agree with @Remou MS-Access does that if a field name has been entered that it cannot find for one reason or another.